# Jquery Array SPServices

Tags: jquery

```
function getBasket() {

  var basketItems = [];
  $().SPServices({
  operation: "GetListItems",
  async: false,
  webURL: "sites/230080/TEST/",
  listName: "Basket",
  CAMLViewFields: "
  <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Item' /></ViewFields>",
  CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /> <Value Type='Integer'>
  <UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query>",

 completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
 $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

 basketItems.push($(this).attr("ows_Item")); //Adds the items to an array




 });}

 });
 }
```

I basically want to be able to list unique items in the array, and display the amount of times an item has been added to the basket

So if I had

```
 1
 1
 2
 3
 3
```

I'd actually want the output to be

```
| Item  | Quantity |
--------------------
|  1    |     2    |
|  2    |     1    |
|  3    |     2    |
```

Please advise on how I would go about achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It this something that you are looking for?

I assumed the values you posted.

```
var result = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3];

var basketItems = [];

$.each(result, function (i, item) {
    var current = basketItems[item] || 0;
    basketItems[item] = current +1;
});

console.log(basketItems);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SWm2s/4/

Comment: Almost, I now need to map these values against the original results so that I can output the result array against the amount of times the element appears

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: Basically I am trying to count the "Items" in my "Basket". The basket contains individual items which I guess I want to group and output the  item name and the number of times it appears in the "Basket"

Comment: after that function `basketItems.length` is the ammount of distinct items you have in your basket